# Me inserta datos codificados

Tags: php, mysql

quiero  insertar datos de registro de usuario en dos tablas, me inserta los datos, pero en el campo password me lo inserta así wfhhZVB_76 para todos los registros.

Mi tabla es así

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS usuarios (
id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
usuarios_establecidos VARCHAR(90) NOT NULL,
password VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
fecha_registro TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
)";
```

Recibo las variables del formulario ya le hice un echo a la variable password y me mostró el valor muy bien.

Luego para insertar los valores hago esto

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0)

{ 
echo"usuario existe";



} else{

echo "usuario completamente registrado";
$sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios_establecidos (usuario, password)

VALUES ('$usuario', '$password')";

$sql2 = "INSERT INTO cuenta_afiliados (usuarios_amigos, usuarios, suma_amigos)

VALUES ('$usuario_amigos', '$usuario', '1')";
mysqli_query ($conn, $sql); 
mysqli_query ($conn, $sql2);

}
```

El formulario:

```
echo " 
<form action=segundo.php method=post> 
Nomre de Usuario: <input type=text name=usuario><br> 
Correo Electronico: <input type=email name=email><br>
Contraseña: <input type=password name=password><br>
Repetir Contraseña: <input type= password name=password1><br>
 <input type=submit value=Enviar> </form>
";
```

Comment: ¿Seguro que no haces ningún manejo del dato antes de insertarlo?

Comment: Recogía las variables del formulario:$usuario = htmlspecialchars($_POST["usuario"]);
$email = htmlspecialchars($_POST["email"]);
$password = htmlspecialchars($_POST["password"]);
$password1 = htmlspecialchars($_POST["password1"]);pero ya le quite el htmlspecialchars pero sigue guardandome lo mismo

Comment: Yo revisaría el javascript de la página, a ver si hay alguna libreria que codifique el posteo, de hecho yo uso un par de ellas para codificar los passwords de los usuarios.

Comment: Tiene que haber una manipulación del dato en alguna parte. Verifica cómo llegan los datos desde el cliente mediante un  `var_dump($_POST);`, si a ese nivel está todo bien podría ser algún TRIGGER o evento que se dispara al momento del INSERT y que modifica el dato.

Comment: Edita la pregunta para agregar código del formulario y cómo creas las variables en PHP.

Comment: Ya hice var_dump al parecer todo bien:{ ["usuario"]=> string(9) "Castanuez" ["email"]=> string(20) "bobloquito@gmail.com" ["password"]=> string(9) "123456789" ["password1"]=> string(9) "123456789" }

Comment: Listo ya edite la pregunta @Triby

Comment: Si hasta llegar a las puertas del INSERT está todo bien y luego los datos aparecen de otro modo sgnifica que en la base de datos debe haber algún `TRIGGER` que se dispara al momento del INSERT y modifica los datos, no le veo otra explicación. O, algo menos probable, pero no descartable: ¡estás revisando en otra tabla/base de datos! ... o, menos probable todavía, hay en tu casa una mascota que sabe de base de datos y ha codificado la información mientras te tomabas un café :) Me intriga saber el motivo, así que averigua y nos informas.

Comment: Estoy trabajando con dos tablas pero en la misma base de datos

Comment: Lo que eran datos codificado era la contraseña de mi base de datos, la que inserta en el campo password, ya le cambie el nombre del campo pero sigue igual. Otro punto que encontré es que al mismo tiempo de hacer el insert también le estoy haciendo un update a la tabla cuenta_usuarios.`$cuenta = "SELECT  suma_traidos FROM cuenta_afiliados WHERE usuarios_establecidos= '".$usuarios_establecidos."'  ";
$result = $conn->query($cuenta);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  // output data of each row
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     $numero=$row["suma_traidos"]+1;